# ajax and php error : Undefined index: userid in my case

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

where have I went wrong?

```
$http({
url: "php/loaduser.php?userid=user_id",
method: "GET",
data: {'user_id':'1'}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    mydata = [];
    mydata = data;
    console.log(mydata);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   // $scope.status = status;
   alert(status);
});
```

my php

```
echo $_GET['user_id'];
```

it return Undefined index: user_id

Answer (score 1):

You are sending in the string `user_id`.

```
url: "php/loaduser.php?userid=user_id"
```

Remove that last query parameter.

Change it to this:

```
url: "php/loaduser.php"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call should be like

```
$http({
    url: "php/loaduser.php",
    method: "GET",
    data: {'user_id':'1'}
})
```

Or either you can use

```
$http({
    url: "php/loaduser.php?user_id=" + user_id,
    method: "GET"
})
```

In second Method you are directly passing the `user_id` through the url whereas in the first you are sending it in a variable manner

Comment: then where you are getting `user_id`.

Comment: still return the same error, no idea what's going on

Answer (score 0):

try this--

```
$.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"php/loaduser.php",
      data: {'user_id':1}
      success:function(data, status, headers, config){
           ydata = [];
           mydata = data;
           console.log(mydata);
      }),
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // $scope.status = status;
         alert(status);
       }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The key in your URL is wrong: you need to change it from `userid` to `user_id`.
Then, you don't need to set the data property, you can include the parameter in your URL like so:

```
url: "php/loaduser.php?user_id=" + '1'
```